# How synchronize get and save in crawler

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is shortcut code of web-crawler that runs on [Crawler](https://npmjs.org/package/crawler) and it's work well. The problem is that the crawler returns 20 strings for half of a second and they are storing in MySQL much slower than the new comes. How properly synchronize this both processes.

```
function crawler(done) {
  for (i=0, ...) { 
    crawler.queue([{
      "uri": link,
      "callback": function (error, result, $) {
        var arr = $('.someclass');
        done(arr);  
      }
   }])
 };
};

crawler (function (arr) {
  savetosql(s, arr);
});

function savetosql (s, arr) {
  var query = connection.query('UPDATE ...');
};
```

Comment: instead of using a for(i=0; i<100; i++) construct, to serialize async calls use
`function crawl_step(step){
     asyncfunc(.... , function(){ if(step<100)crawl_step(step+1);  })
}`

Comment: had same problem with creating a benchmark over ab

Comment: Although I agree with +Avner-Solomon, you could still end up with a giant backlog of SQL calls, that builds increasingly over time.

Have you considered switching your database to MongoDB?

Comment: Totally agree with @outrunthewolf . Waiting after each call will really slow you down , but if you want I can write a detailed answer on node.js serialization

Comment: @AvnerSolomon for(i=0; i<100; i++) for iterating the set of links from object. Maybe somewhere input "setTimeout()"?

Comment: @AvnerSolomon I'm in no hurry, please write

Comment: @outrunthewolf i'm using MongoDB there but for another usecase

Comment: @Ligamentum  think your problem is that for every crawl you run the done callback. What I meant is something like do_first_crawl->store_it_in_db->do_2nd->store_it_in_db etc. Isn't this what you want? But this is gonna be very slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nnot sure if this is what you're looking for, I never used crawler but this is how you serialize stuff in node.js.

```
function crawl_step(step,limit) {
  //for (i=0, ...) { no more for
    crawler.queue([{
      "uri": link,
      "callback": function (error, result, $) {
        var arr = $('.someclass');
        //done(arr);
        var query = connection.query('UPDATE ...',calbback(...){
            //this runs when the sql query is over
            if(step<limit) crawl_step(step+1,limit);
            else {....do something when all crawls are over ...}
        });
      }
   }])
 //};
};

crawl_step(0,100);
```

To make it easier to understand the serialization process let's work on some basic api:
we want to read 100 files only if they exist (and we use the async calls, but in a sync manner).

```
function step(step_nr){
    fs.exists( step_nr+'.txt' , function (exists) {
        fs.readFile( step_nr+'.txt' , function (err, data) {
           if (err) throw err;
           console.log(data);
           if(step_nr<100) step(step_nr+1);
        });
    });
}
step(0);
```